# Push Notification Arrival Time

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

Is there any way to get Push notification arrival time?
For example, my app is killed or in background state. Then a notification came, But I click after 30 minutes. Now can I get the arrival time of Notification? Is there any way to get time from NSNotificationCenter of APNS?

Comment: Any research you did on silent push notifications introduced from iOS 7?

Comment: yes you can..Your server should send the JSON data  that contains trigger time of push notification in the JSON format...through this method didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: @anishparajuli It might be possible, But there would be chances of time mismatch of Server and System. It is not the efficient solution.

Comment: @SankarNarayanan Yes, I know about silent Notification. But could not help in my case. Because user should also aware about push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Never, You cant get the time of arrived push notification. I am sure about this.